# Convert dictionary or tuples to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I am doing a web scraping exercise where the scraped words are counted by occurrence. I want to convert counted words and frequency into a dataframe and save in excel format.

I have tried every example but nothing works.
I want to convert this list (top), which looks like this

```
 Print (top)
 [('the', 1)]
 [('one', 1)]
 [('of', 1)]
 [('the', 1)]
 [('most', 1)]
 ...........
```

into a dataframe like this:

```
 index Word count
  ..    the   1
  ..    one   1
  ..    of    1
  ..    the   1
  ..    most  1
  ..    ...   ..
```

the is the lower part of the code

```
 for word in clean_list: 
       if word in word_count: 
           word_count[word] += 1
       else: 
           word_count[word] = 1

  #To get count of each word in 
      #the crawled page --> 

  c = Counter(word_count)

  # returns the most occuring elements 
  top = c.most_common(100)
```

This is my code where it is not working:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(top, columns=["word","count"])
df.to_excel("mine" + ".xls")
print(top)
```

It only saves the last line and not the whole list.
I will be happy if someone can help. Thank you!

Full code is:
`

```
# Python3 program for a word frequency 
# counter after crawling a web-page 
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import operator 
from collections import Counter 
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

'''Function defining the web-crawler/core 
spider, which will fetch information from 
a given website, and push the contents to 
the second function clean_wordlist()'''
def start(url): 

# empty list to store the contents of 
# the website fetched from our web-crawler 
    wordlist = [] 
    source_code = requests.get(url).text 

# BeautifulSoup object which will 
# ping the requested url for data 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser') 

# Text in given web-page is stored under 
# the <div> tags with class <entry-content> 
    for each_text in soup.findAll('div', {'class':'entry-content'}): 
        content = each_text.text 

# use split() to break the sentence into 
# words and convert them into lowercase 
    words = content.lower().split() 

    for each_word in words: 
        wordlist.append(each_word) 
        clean_wordlist(wordlist)



# Function removes any unwanted symbols 
def clean_wordlist(wordlist): 

    clean_list =[] 
    for word in wordlist: 
        symbols = '!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\;:"<>?/., '

    for i in range (0, len(symbols)): 
        word = word.replace(symbols[i], '') 

    if len(word) > 0: 
        clean_list.append(word) 
    create_dictionary(clean_list)


# Creates a dictionary conatining each word's 
# count and top_20 ocuuring words 
def create_dictionary(clean_list): 
    word_count = {} 
    dateObj =time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    df=[]
    other={}

    for word in clean_list: 
        if word in word_count: 
            word_count[word] += 1
        else: 
            word_count[word] = 1

    c = Counter(word_count)

    # returns the most occuring elements 
    top = c.most_common(100)

    #df=pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(top), columns=['Word', 'Count'])
    df=pd.DataFrame.from_records([i[0] for i in top])
    df.to_excel("mine" + ".xls")
    #print(top)
    print(top)


# Driver code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    start("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/programming-language-choose/")`
```

Comment: Don't forget the most relevant tag: `pandas`, for pandas related questions

Comment: Already added @ScottBoston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code. The most common mistake was overwriting data during loops.

Like here, you replace the content over and over!

```
for each_text in soup.findAll('div', {'class':'entry-content'}): 
        content = each_text.text
```

And here, you overwrite your output file over and over.

```
for each_word in words: 
        wordlist.append(each_word) 
        clean_wordlist(wordlist)
```

I have rewritten it in a single function, you can split it into more functions if you wish.

```
#Add imports...


def process(url): 

    # the website fetched from our web-crawler 
    source_code = requests.get(url).text 

    # BeautifulSoup object which will 
    # ping the requested url for data 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser') 

    # Text in given web-page is stored under 
    # the <div> tags with class <entry-content>
    entry_content = ''
    for content in soup.findAll('div', {'class':'entry-content'}): 
        entry_content += content.text.strip()

    #clean
    entry_content = entry_content.lower()
    symbols = list('!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\;:"<>?/., ')
    symbols.append('\n') #new line char

    for symbol in symbols:
        entry_content = entry_content.replace(symbol,' ')
    #print(entry_content)

    #split in words
    words = entry_content.split()

    #conut words
    c = Counter(words)

    #remove white spaces
    if ' ' in c:
        del c[' ']

    #write to excell the most common words
    most_common_words = c.most_common(100)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(most_common_words, columns=['Word', 'Count'])
    df.to_excel("mine.xls")

# Driver code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    process("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/programming-language-choose/")
```

Comment: I apologize for the late reply but thank you so much!!! It works like a charm!! I have upvoted it. @alec_djinn